# question mark in required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

If I'm defining a view I need the following. What does the question mark in `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` mean?

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: It means it returns an optional. For instance if you have an "important" param in your init, and that param doesn't respects your needs, you might want to return nil instead of an instance that's not correct.

Comment: See "Failable Initializers" in the Swift Programming Language. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html